# how to access Application and Database on AWS as local from other network

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Recently I created a micro instance of Amazon EC2 (Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2014_RTM_Express-2014.05.20).
I configured IIS on AWS and create a database respectively.
that is one scenario. Another is I have my own server.
specifications:
windows server 2008,
DHCP, static IP,
Active Directory,
RRAS

now I want to access Application and database from my own server (domain users) with windows authentication mode. I know there is no additional cost for the VPC but for VPN there is $. 48 per hour so I don't want to pay .48 cents per hour that would cost $11.52 per day.
Any one have an Idea for how I can(domain user) access  My Application and Database (stored on AWS) with windows authentication mode or log in as local.

Comment: Welcome to SF. Your question is hard to read, lots of technology and pricing details. Can you whittle it down to what you actually need help with?

Comment: Your figures are inaccurate.  Hardware VPN connections are neither "$.48" per hour nor ".48 cents" ... the correct number is $0.048/hr for Tokyo and $0.05/hr in other regions. http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/

Comment: Hello Felix, Its not hard to understand. I just mention What's on my server and AWS.I want my active directory user's (My own server 2008 R2) accessibility as local on AWS